How to modify a "Name+2nd name+Surname without touch 2nd name? Phyton
I want to change 2 characters in a variable in phyton but when I fix one the other change again.
I have this variable.
name= " rIana Danyela RodrYguez " 

I don't want to touch the name "Danyela".
If i want to replace "I" in "rIana" by "Y" and "Y" in "RodrYguez" by "i" I made this line.
.print(nombre.strip() delete spaces
.lower() lower all letters.
.title() Capitalizes 1st letter of each word.
then .replace ("i","y",)) of riana gives me "ryana"
BUT,when I try to replace "y" in rodyguez with .replace ("y","i",) I get rodriguez but "ryana" becomes "riana" again. The I got a loop when I try to fix it.
I found that i can try to change "RodrYguez" first with
print(nombre.strip().replace("Y", "i").lower().title().replace ("i","y", 1,))

then I got my solution but I want to replace this caracters words in 1 move.

XY Problem - Is this really what you're trying to do? Or are you trying to solve a different problem with this method?

You should split the name into its parts, then fix each part individually and then join them again.

I'm dubious of this question, because it is not a generic question.  What you're saying would apply only to this one example.  If the problem is to "replace all capital I with small y and all capital Y with small i", that's a good generic question.

Hi @AndrewYim yes, in fact that my problem. Only change "I" in "rIana" by "Y" and "Y" in "RodrYguez" by "i" with a better solution than I found with my actual knowledge. Tnks, 4 answer.

To put @TimRoberts's comment differently, the best solution to this question as written is "type 'ryana Danyela Rodriguez' on your keyboard"

s.replace('Y','i').replace('I','y') would seem to be the simplest solution.
